# Search a cell for specific 'special characters' and color the cell red if found

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to search a column of cells for any of these special characters:

```
` ‘ “ \ / ^
```

If present (that can also be like `C2="fruit\"`), I want the cell to return a red color.

I know I should use conditional formatting for this and a find function... but how do I combine it with all the characters?

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following as a single conditional formatting rule, where `A1` is the top-left cell of the range.

```
=(IFERROR(FIND("`",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("'",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(34),A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("\",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("/",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("^",A1),0))>0
```

[image]

This formula works by summing the results of individual `FIND`s for each character. The sum is 0 unless at least one of the characters is found.

Answer (score 4):

To do this via Excel formulas, you will have to use Helper Columns.

Let's say you have some text in Col A as shown in the pic below

[image]

Next Type your special characters say in `E1:E6`

Next in B1, type this formula

`=SUM(IF(ISERROR((FIND($E$1:$E$6,A1))),0,1))`

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy the formula down.

[image]

Next highlight COl A and in Home | Conditional Formatting | New Rule, Select `Use a Formula to determine which cells to format`

Next Type the formula `=$B1>0` as shown in the screenshot and you are done

[image]

This is the output

[image]

Hide Col B/E if needed.

Comment: +1. Note that you don't need the helper column - you could just put it in the CF. Here's my favorite formula to do this: `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & $E$1:$E$6 &"*" ))>0`,

Comment: @DougGlancy: you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: I'd rather just hang out here with you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=or(IFERROR(FIND(",",C2)>0,FALSE),
    IFERROR(FIND("^",C2)>0,FALSE),
    etc
```

made in seperate lines to make it more readable... obviously you need to remove line breaks.   Can add that As conditional formatting as it returns a TRUE if one or more of characters are found FALSE if None were found.

```
IFERROR(FIND(",",C2)>0,FALSE)
```

is the key to kinding if character is in a cell.

Comment: Hi thx for the help :)! But got some small errors I think with the syntax.... can you help? Not really an expert:

Comment: Siddharth's Solution more complete than mine.  Will keep mine here for bit then delete. Mine shows slightly different approach, his more elegant   Could roll his calc in column b into the Conditional formatting calc

Comment: ok but yours works fine to, I'll try his two thanks for helping me